# Can't install jxcore-cordova

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, jxcore

I want to host a Node.js server on my Android device. So when looking around i stumbled over jxcore-cordova...especially this site [Sitepoint How to run Node.js on Mobile](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-run-node-js-with-express-on-mobile-devices/)

Following this tutorial i got the bat and also the sh and ran it. First i got the eror that the command jx can not be found. So i installed JXCore for Windows from here: [JXCore Github Releases](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore-release)

Afterwards i get these errors:

```
module.js:2098
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Package is either corrupted or not compatible with this JX binary. (....\.jx\npmjxv311.jx)
    at Object.Module._extensions..jx (module.js:2095:15)
    at Module.load (module.js:440:36)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:405:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:878:12)
    at startup (node.js:485:18)
    at node.js:1604:3
Downloading the file. Please wait...

module.js:802
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '....\jxcore-cord
ova\hello\node_modules\download-cli\cli.js'
    at Function.Module._oldRes (module.js:800:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:1768:19)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:360:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:878:12)
    at startup (node.js:485:18)
    at node.js:1604:3
Der Befehl "rm" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.

module.js:802
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '....\jxcore-cord
ova\hello\io.jxcore.node.jx'
    at Function.Module._oldRes (module.js:800:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:1768:19)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:360:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:878:12)
    at startup (node.js:485:18)
    at node.js:1604:3
Incorrect sample folder 'io.jxcore.node\sample\express_sample\www'.
```

Thinking that maybe you have to go through the "Installation" steps on the [JXCore-Cordova Github page](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore-cordova) i started doing that but when executing android_compile.sh with the path to the downloaded Android NPK i get the out_android folder and some other folders but they are all empty.

Now my questions are:
**Am I missing something or am i doing something wrong?
And is jxcore-cordova still the best (and only) way to run a node.js app on Android?**

Btw: I looked through stackoverflow and found no other questions with this error. The ones that sound similar solved it with one of the things i tried and failed with. I also tried a different 2 different PCs with the install_and_run file but no difference.

Comment: FWIW: Active development on JXcore [has been halted](http://www.nubisa.com/nubisa-halting-active-development-on-jxcore-platform/).

Comment: From what i heard JXcore was turned into an open-source project and judging from the [JXCore Github Repository](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore) it has been updated 10 days ago.

If that is wrong though...is there another  way now to run node.js servers on Android? I heard somewhere that there are android distributions for Android but haven't found a way to install or run these.

Comment: If you read the article they note that they are still accepting PRs for bug fixes at this time, but not new features. That is why there is still repo activity. Also, the announcement was on March 25th, 2016, so it hasn't been that long ago.

Comment: Thanks for that Information but I still feel like it should have worked. Okay the install_and_run.bat not finding the files online could be because of that but the basic Compilation of the Android environment still shouldn't have returned empty folders. They seem to want to freeze the current state of the project but that state seem to work for others people...so why not for me. And if there is no way to get jxcore to work now....what else is there?

Comment: Looking around i couldn't really find any other solutions. Most of them either only seem to be run when the Device is connected to a PC when you want to start the Node.js app (which is not ideal) or involve installing another OS on your device which also is not an option here.

Is rewriting the entire server in Java the only option here?