# Run Node.js project on Android non rooted device

Tags: android, node.js

Please, help me, to run this Node.js github project https://github.com/sjitech/tunnel.js on Android 4.2+ non rooted device.

I can run it with termux, but how can I run it from Android Studio?

Is it possible to run it without terminal?

I can pay for the working solution.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36632649/running-node-js-on-android

Comment: Thanks, I have look this topic. Is it possible to run it without terminal with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have done it with https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore.