# How do I implement a webhook in Android?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, webhooks

I want to have URL for example`www.example.com/status` in my Android app to which I will be observing and will be receiving multiple POST requests from the Server. With each POST request, I will trigger a feature. I don't understand how can I implement a listener on a URL 24x7. All I want is a place to start with. If this is not possible then is Push Notifications a viable option?

Note: The webhook isn't supposed to be on the Server instead it should be on the Client (Android) and Server is supposed to send requests on the webhook.

Comment: I would suggest reading about nodejs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36632649/running-node-js-on-android

Answer (score -3):

You can use firebase push notification . Use a web server to send push notification to your application, and perform the action inside the Firebase Event service.

Comment: So, does that mean the webhook implementation is not possible?

Comment: You can easily done it with firebase . its the most common platform ,and having so many other features like crash analytics

Comment: I'll give that a try.

Comment: Link to appropriate firebase documentation is required or relevant parts of the documentation should be quoted here to implement a webhook.