# Android app with webhook

Tags: android, webhooks

I'm trying to build an android app that uses a webhook to receive a notification and then trigger an action in the app.  My plan is to create the webhook with hook.io and setup Firebase to receive the notification ([How do I implement a webhook in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336811/how-do-i-implement-a-webhook-in-android)). I'm new to Android and webhooks so I'm not sure if this method will work or if there is a better way to do it. I also found a Webhook API (https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/android/handle_push_notifications_wh) and (https://github.com/predict-io/PredictIO-Android/wiki/Using-Webhooks), but they both seem to only deal with sending notifications to a webhook, whereas I want to receive a notification.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68636552/8956093